# Docker Desktop Linux crashing & KVM not loading

Tags: 22.04, intel, docker, kvm-virtualization, modprobe

I have installed Docker Desktop Linux on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. After I start it and wait for some seconds, it throws this error:

> **Something went wrong**

> Waiting for qemu process: exit status 1

I assume that the problem is that KVM has not even been loaded. I have checked this point using `lsmod | grep kvm` and I got this result:

```
kvm_intel             503808  0
kvm                  1347584  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
```

Research (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/KVM/ in German) suggested that latter output means that KVM has not been loaded. When I try to load KVM by typing `sudo modprobe kvm && sudo modprobe kvm-intel` into the terminal, the result of `lsmod | grep kvm` still remains the same as before.

I don't know how to solve this issue and need your help. I have installed all the required packages for KVM (https://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-kvm-on-ubuntu-22-04/) and followed the KVM support activation step in the docker desktop linux installation guide (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support). Furthermore, I have activated virtualization in the CPU configurations of my boot menu.

If you need more information, I will give my best to provide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downgrading Docker Desktop from 4.26.1 to 4.25.0. This helped fix the initial issue `Something went wrong: Waiting for qemu process: exit status 1` so that Docker Desktop runs without any crashes.